# Upload images in custom modules

Tags: files, media

I work on D7, and create form from custom modules. Create a field upload images by 
$form['#attributes']['enctype'] = 'multipart/form-data';
$form['image'] = array(

```
'#type' => 'file',

'#title' => t('Upload picture'),

'#description' => t('Select a picture of at least @dimensionspx and maximum @filesize.', array(

  '@dimensions' => '1000x1000',

  '@filesize' => format_size(file_upload_max_size()),

)),
```

);

Show form correct.

[image]

and submit form by hook_form_submit();
print $form_state, upload images not find.
How to get values of upload image.

Write Also

$file = file_save_upload('image', array(
    'file_validate_is_image' => array(),
    'file_validate_image_resolution' => array('500x500', '100x100'),
  ), 'public://uploaded_images/', FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);

Not find of upload image.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal makes a distinction between regular files and managed files. The first are only stored on the filesystem, the second are stored in the database (managed) as well.

If you use a [manged file](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/#managed_file) (type = 'managed_file') the `$form_state` will contain a file id (fid) of the newly stored image.

Also note that `file_save_upload` takes the file path as the first parameter, so 'image' means nothing there. And that you still have to store your image as a permanent file after `file_save_upload()`:

```
$file = file_load($logo);
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
file_save($file);
file_usage_add($file, 'your_module', 'using_entity_type', $entity_id);
```

Answer (score -2):

The values are in $_FILES.

You shouldn't need to set the enctype of the form, Drupal will handle that for you automatically.

Comment: Weird that someone down-voted me, considering I answered the question that was asked.